# Double integration of standard truncated normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution

I've been struggling working on the following double integration. 
Given that $U$ is truncated normal distribution where $0<U<\inf$ and $f_U(u)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp{\frac{-U^2}{2}}$.
I need to simplify $$\int_{u=0}^{\inf}\int_{t=-\inf}^{hu+k}2\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp^{\frac{-U^2}{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp^{\frac{-t^2}{2}}dt.du$$

I am interested in simplifying the double integration into one integration of some truncated standard normal distribution.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Under what context did you encounter this integral?

Comment: Thank you for your followup. I was trying to write $E_U[\Phi (hU+k)]$ in the form $\Phi(?)$ where $U$ is truncated normal distribution.